# Можно ли подключиться к Remote Desktop через Proxy на целевой системе?

Tags: windows, proxy, rdp

*Допустим* есть ПК на удалёнке, к которому можно подключиться по Proxy (SOCKS5). Этот ПК находится за NAT. Надо подключиться к RDP (который allowed) на этой системе. Доступа к роутеру нет (чтобы сделать проброс портов). Настравию ОС (proxy), чтобы весь трафик шёл через ту (удалённую) систему. Трафик действительно идёт через неё. Но вот не знаю как подключиться к RDP используя этот Proxy. Если это вообще возможно. Подключаюсь к proxy через 127.0.0.1:1234 (proxy открывается на моей системе, но выход на удалённой). Какой IP (может и порт) указать при подключении по mstsc.exe чтобы подключиться к этой удалённой системе на которой и стоит выход proxy? Или в данной ситуации это невозможно? Или заменить Proxy VPN-ом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это возможно.

Используйте утилиту [connect](https://gist.github.com/rurban/360940).
Запускаете с параметрами:

```
connect -P 13389 -H <proxy-server>:<proxy-port> <host-to-control LAN IP> 3389
```

Если вы хотите подключиться по RDP к тому же компьютеру, где у вас установлен SOCKS5 сервер, то `<host-to-control LAN IP>` будет `127.0.0.1`

Затем соединяетесь при помощи RDP клиента на адрес 127.0.0.1:13389 Вашего локального компьютера

Аналогичный фокус можно провернуть при помощи Putty, если есть SSH доступ к удаленной системе.

Источник - [переписка на Гитхабе по программе mRemoteNG](https://github.com/mRemoteNG/mRemoteNG/issues/420)

Comment: В <host-to-control LAN IP> понятно что вставлять. А какие значения задавать для <proxy-server>:<proxy-port>?

Comment: А вот координаты  Вашего прокси и задавайте: `127.0.0.1:1234`